# state variables are coupled with reducer names in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

This might be a really silly one, but I was hanging my head around it for a while. I have a React project ( with Redux ). In `mapStateToProps`, state value is coming as `undefined` if I try to access the state directly as

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ data: state.data });
```

Instead, I always have to specify my reducer name ( the reducer which handles this particular state in it )  to access the state value :

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ data: state.customReducer.data });
```

Here is my code :

```
import { combinedReducer } from 'redux;
import customReducer from './customReducer'; 

const rootReducer = combineReducer({
      customReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

customReducer.js : as follows

```
  const initialState = {};

    const customReducer = ( state = initialState, action ) => {
         const { type, payload } = action;

         switch (type) {
               case 'SOME_ACTION':
                    return {
                         ...state,
                         data: payload.data
                    }
                    break;

               default:
                     return state;
         }
    } 

export default customReducer;
```

store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

const configStore = () => {
     return createStore (
           rootReducer,
           applyMiddleware(thunk)
     );
} 

const store = configStore();

export default store;
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong with the implementation ? Or is it the way to access different state values from different store ?

How can I directly access any state variable as

```
data: state.`state_value` , instead of ,  data : state.`reducerName`.`state_value` ?
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your implementation, this is just the way that [`combineReducers`](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers) works. The reducer names are used to partition your store (e.g. Everything in your `users` reducer will be under `state.users`).

If you don't want to have to use the name of the reducer in your `mapStateToProps`, you can use [selectors](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data). However, in the selector, you will still have to use `state.reducerName`.

If you really don't want to have to go through more than one layer to get to the value you want, you could create a separate reducer for each value (i.e. In your example, the reducer would be named `data`). This obviously isn't the preferred way of doing it though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `combineReducers` isn't really using the reducer name, but the property name you specify for it. If you do:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducer({
  foo: customReducer,
});
```

You'll be able to access the data at `state.foo.data`.